# How to partition and install Ubuntu?

Tags: 12.04, boot, grub2, partitioning

I'm using my Ubuntu LIVE 12.04 LTS CD because I have no other OS that is functional.
My Vista Home Premium 64-bit crashed repeatedly, and I have no intention of paying for anymore Windows OS.

Here's my problem: Ubuntu will ONLY boot from the CD I created.

> No such device, grub rescue errors on boot Disc read error.

I partitioned over 30 Gigs of space on my external Toshiba drive for the Ubuntu Install (I have NO CLUE what I am doing here).

The forums say to try to fix it myself, and I have looked at so many posts with install issues that my head is "swimming"!

Now I am in deep... Vista will not boot at all, can't even access the files on it.
I don't know what I am doing, there is a RED **"!"** next to my Main Hard drive (500 Gig) (NTFS) (NOT MOUNTED) and the error does not display completely in GParted - I don't know how to copy that error list and it's not scrollable. What it DOES say is:

```
**Filesystem Check failed.
40186 clusters are referenced multiple times
NTFS is inconsistent. Run chkdsk /f on Windows then  reboot it twice.
```

(um, does that mean on a terminal because I can't load windows? Should I do this or will it get worse?)

```
The usage of the /f parameter is very important. 
No modification was and will be made to NTFS software until it gets repaired.**
Unable to read the contents of the file system.
The cause might be a missing software package.
The following list of software packages is required for NTFS...
```

and that is where the error ends, no scroll, no package list.

As far as my USB External Toshiba Drive (1Tb) is unmounted, I deleted the Ubuntu files and reverted to the "unallocated" 32 Gig partition, so it is empty. But the swap remains.
The "extended" (sbd2) and swap (sbd5) are showing as locked (key showing) in GParted.

After attempting to install Ubuntu 12.04 LTS, wouldn't boot, even with BIOS changed boot drive every way... I uninstalled it, but left the swap as I had read in a few posts.

What do I do to fix this mess?

If I install it on my HDD (500 Gig) overwriting all my files and programs, will it work or will I still have these problems?

This is what I get with sudo `fdisk -l`:

```
Disk /dev/sda: 500.1 GB, 500107862016 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 60801 cylinders, total 976773168 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes

Disk identifier: 0x97646c29

   Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sda1              63    24579449    12289693+   b  W95 FAT32
/dev/sda2        24579450   976771119   476095835    7  HPFS/NTFS/exFAT

Disk /dev/sdb: 1500.3 GB, 1500301910016 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 182401 cylinders, total 2930277168 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x525d39b7

   Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sdb1   *        2048  2849062911  1424530432    7  HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
/dev/sdb2      2849064958  2930276351    40605697    5  Extended
/dev/sdb5      2917697536  2930276351     6289408   82  Linux swap / Solaris
ubuntu@ubuntu:~$
```

UPDATE: BOTH drives now MOUNTED. The NEW fdisk results are:

```
Disk /dev/sda: 500.1 GB, 500107862016 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 60801 cylinders, total 976773168 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x97646c29

   Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sda1              63    24579449    12289693+   b  W95 FAT32
/dev/sda2   *    24579450   976771119   476095835    7  HPFS/NTFS/exFAT

Disk /dev/sdb: 1500.3 GB, 1500301910016 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 182401 cylinders, total 2930277168 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x525d39b7

   Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sdb1            2048  2849062911  1424530432    7  HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
/dev/sdb2      2849064958  2930276351    40605697    5  Extended
/dev/sdb5      2917697536  2930276351     6289408   82  Linux swap / Solaris
```

Comment: Your issue is one about fixing Windows.  You need to boot into recovery mode for Vista (or boot to a Vista disk and use it's repair mode) to repair the NTFS partition for Windows.  However, to get help with that, you should ask on another site, such as [Super User](superuser.com) as this site here does *not* help with Windows repair using the Windows utilities.

Comment: You should use `ext3` or `ext4` file format for your Ubuntu OS ("/"). You can also make another partition for your Home dirrectories ("/Home"), where you can store all your data. You won't loose it even you have to reinstall your OS...

Comment: OK, I can now access and see files on BOTH drives. I was getting an error saying the Gpart was not installed, so I copy/pasta the following into the terminal:    sudo apt-get purge gparted && sudo apt-get install gparted   and the GPart started working again. Now the NTFS 500 Gig HDD is seen again  with NO RED ! next to it. I can access the files once again, YAY...    now I just have to figure out how to install correctly.

Comment: Where do you want to install Ubuntu? On the external hard disk? I suggest installing it on your internal 500GB HDD by freeing up some space for it.

Comment: You asked "_If I install it on my HDD (500 Gig) overwriting all my files and programs, will it work or will I still have these problems?_" No, you won't have problems, it will install just fine. You can install Ubuntu, completely removing Windows with all its data, or you can install Ubuntu alongside Windows, so that when you boot up your computer, you'll be asked to either boot into Ubuntu or Windows, and you won't lose any of your data in Windows. Which would you prefer?

Comment: the alongside didn't work, what I would have preferred. now will try it again on the "something else". I did notice that the RED ! is back on my Main HDD (C Drive or sda1) in Gpart and the files seem to have installed on my External 1TB (sdb) , something ain't right... thanks for any help y'all are trying to give me! I truly appreciate it.

Comment: @LyricLover What went wrong with your "alongside" installation? I can post an answer, but I want to know what happened when you tried.

Answer (score 0):

Your master boot record is corrupted.

Put in your Vista install CD.

Boot into a command prompt.

Type 'fdisk /mbr' and press Enter.

Reboot.